# Grant privileges on MariaDB?

Tags: privileges, mariadb

I'm following some tutorial to install Zabbix on my CentOS 7.2
Here's the command line used to create zabbix database and give privileges

```
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> create database zabbix; 
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]> grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@'localhost' identified by 'password'; 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]> grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@'%' identified by 'password'; 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]> flush privileges; 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]> exit 
Bye
```

I don't understand the command used to grant privileges to zabbix@'%'. What's the meaning of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the hostname is '%' it will match a connection request from any host - **except** `localhost` a pretty important distinction!
In other words, if you ran the command

```
grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@'%' identified by 'password';
```

Because `%` is a kind of "wildcard" host, you might thing that means user `zabbix` can connect from remote machines **and** localhost.
However if `zabbix` tries to connect from the same system the SQL server was running, Maria DB would deny the connection,

Therefore if you truly want `zabbix` to be able to connect from everywhere you need to run **both**

```
grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@'localhost' identified by 'password';
```

and

```
grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@'%' identified by 'password';
```

Comment: According to [6.2.3 Specifying Account Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/account-names.html) there is no explicit separation of `%` from `localhost`. It's just that _usually_ `127.0.0.1` will resolve to `localhost` rather than the host's name.

Answer (score 2):

The [MySQL reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connection-access.html) explains it very well. Here is a quick summary

Split the connection identifier into username and originating host

1. The username must match the username with which you are authentication
2. If the hostname is '%' it will match any originating hostname
3. Otherwise the hostname must match either as a literal DNS name